# Why was this answer deleted (it was a second identical answer)?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

See *[How to use Intl.NumberFormat with react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812751/how-to-use-intl-numberformat-with-react-native/70684248?noredirect=1#comment124958116_70684248)*

I understand that posting the same (short) answer for different questions is not desired, but in this case I think it is helpful for visitors of these questions to have this answer in place. It is very relevant: it answers the questions for newer versions of a library in combination with another oft-used library.

Comment: Either something is not desired or it is allowed. You can't cherry pick between the two whenever you like ....

Comment: _posting the same (short) answer for different questions is not desired_: Isn't the question self-explanatory?

Comment: OK, I mean, "not desired in general"

Answer (score 13):

We don't want identical answers. The moderator explained that when they deleted both of your answers:

> Please [don't post duplicate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227), especially not ones that are little more than links to external resources. If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer fully on site and then vote to close the other(s) as duplicates. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

Just pick the best Q/A pair, content-wise, write an awesome up-to-date answer (for example with some code how to use that feature) to improve that Q/A even more, close vote the other question as a duplicate of the one you just improved.

Comment: @pors why do you feel this doesn't answer your question? What information you think is missing?

Comment: @pors I have the feeling I missed another opportunity to explain that we need only one version of a question with all its possible answers. I'm attached to your knowledge. Please follow the given advice and post a better answer on *one* question, dupe vote the other. You have that close privilege. Use it.